# Find coordinates of points in 3d by given distance as optimization-problem

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms

So assume you have $n$ points in 3d. 
You know that some (but not all) pairs of points have distance $=1$. 
The other pairs of points have distance $\leq 1$ to each other, but are closest to $1$ as possible.

Now I want to find their coordinates.

My idea:

$$ max \sum_{i,j=1,..,n} dist(i,j)     \\
s.t. \quad dist(\cdot, \cdot) \leq 1 \qquad for \ all \ points \\
and \quad dist(\cdot, \cdot) = 1 \qquad for \ some\ pairs\ of\ points $$

where $\quad$ $dist(i,j)= \sqrt{(i_x-j_x)^2+(i_y-j_y)^2+(i_z-j_z)^2}  $ $\quad$ is the distance between point $i$ and point $j$.

(Is this correct? )

Is there an algorithm to give one possible solution?

I have seen some questions, where the whole distance matrix was given but in this case there are some open entries in the matrix.

I am open to any kind of suggestions. Thanks in advance! 
$\tiny(sorry \ if \ english \ is \ bad, \ I´m \ not \ an \ native\ english \ speaker)$

Comment: The points are on the surface of a sphere with radius $1/2$.  I do not know their distribution, but it is one that maximizes the sum of their pairwise distances.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? If one Point is the North Pole and the other on the South Pole, then their distance is 1. But where do I place a third point which has distance 1 to the other two points?

Comment: In $N$ dimensions, you can place exactly $N+1$ points with all their pairwise distances being the same.  The polytope this forms is called [a simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).  In 3D, it is the regular tetrahedron.  You can then add any number of points within the simplex, and their pairwise distances will be smaller.  However, the volume of that simplex ($1/\sqrt{72}$) is smaller than that of a ball ($\pi/6$), which means that putting the points inside that ball will yield larger distances.  In particular, you can have any number of pairs with distance $1$, by putting them [..]

Comment: [...] at opposite sides of the ball.  Because the ball has the largest volume among convex polytopes with diameter $1$, the distances between points will be maximized.  I do not know the optimal *distribution*, however; that's why this is not an answer.

Comment: Thats a interesting construction for $N$ dimensions! Sadly, I´m in 3D with more than 3 points. 
Do you know an algorithm, which can solve a problem where the objective function and constraints are similar to the distance function?

Comment: No, I am afraid I do not; sorry.